# ASP.NET DLL Directory

Tags: .net, iis, web-config

I am trying to configure IIS to look for DLLs in the bin\Debug directory (as opposed to the bin directory).  I tried updating my machine.config (as well as the web.config), with the following line:

```
 <runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <probing privatePath="bin\Debug" />
</assemblyBinding>
```

However, it still doesn't see that directory.  Is there something else I am missing?

Comment: You are swimming against the tide. I'd stop doing that if I were you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly why you're doing this either, but I have a guess that may help you.  You can set the output folder for dlls within Visual Studio.  You get to the screen below by right clicking on your project and selecting **Properties**. Then select the **Build** tab.

Change the output path from bin\ to bin\Debug.  Or, if I'm guessing correctly at your real problem and you have projects outputting to bin\Debug and don't know how to change that, you can change it back from bin\Debug to just bin\.

[image: Build->Output]

Comment: I know how to change the output directory.  The problem was that our build server had a standard output directory (bin\configuration) and I wanted to keep it that way (even on developer PCs).  That was the reason to change IIS.